# slicing a list across several slices

Tags: python, list, slice

I'm looking to slice a list across two or more slices. For example, there is a list:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Let's say I want to slice the list as items 1 to 4 and 6 to 9.

If we do:

```
a[1:5]
```

the output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If we do:

```
a[6:10]
```

the output is:

```
[6, 7, 8, 9]
```

But is there someway to combine multiple slices. Something like:

```
a[1:5 and 6:10]
```

to output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [napuzba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6582873/napuzba)'s suggestion, I'm thinking that the following might be the most efficient way to do this:

```
all_slice = [*a[1:5], *a[6:10]]
```

Where `all_slice` holds:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

This seems pretty pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [list.extend](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) for this task.

```
slice1 = a[1:5]
slice2 = a[6:10]
slice1.extend(slice2)
# now use slice1
```

It appends all the items of the slice2 to the first slice1.

Comment: based on the extend method, i just tried this. any issues with it? seems pretty pythonic:

all_slice = [*a[1:5], *a[6:10]]

Answer (score 1):

There is no special syntax, just append the lists slices:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print(a[1:5]+a[6:10])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid creating the intermediate lists for the individual slices, you could use `itertools.islice` and `chain.from_iterable` to get and combine the slices as iterators.

```
>>> from itertools import chain, islice
>>> slc = [(1,5), (6,10)]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(islice(a, *s) for s in slc))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Also works with 1- or 3-tuples, for just end-, or start-end-step slices.

Comment: simple sum(iterable, []) is faster

Answer (score 0):

If you have several ranges you are trying to slice, you can use the built-in [`slice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) with a list comprehension:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

ranges = [(1, 5), (6, 10)]   

[n for s in ranges for n in a[slice(*s)]]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the answer:

There is no special syntax, just append the lists slices:

a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

print(a[1:5]+a[6:10])

```
                                           FROM -> Aviv Yaniv
```

b, a = a[1:5], a[6:10]

print(b+a)